# undefined method rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show relations between two tables but i get

```
undefined method `guiders' for # <ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Trip:0x3865e78>
```

--controller code for showguiders--

```
class ShowguidersController < ApplicationController
def guidersout
r = Trip.all
@guiders_out = r.guiders
end
end
```

model for guider

```
class Guider < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :trip
end
```

model for trip

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :guides
end
```

view

this is what my professor had on his

```
<center><h1> Here are our Guides </h1>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<table width = 60% border =1>
<tr><th>Guide # </th><th> Name </th> <th> Phone </th> </tr>
<% @guiders_out.each do |m| %>
<tr><td> <%= m.id %> </tr> </td> <tr><td> <%= m.name %> </tr> </td> <tr><td> <%=   m.phone %> </tr> </td>
<% end %>
</table></center>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
```

Comment: You need to use guides instead of guiders

Comment: Did you mean to write `has_many :guiders` instead of `has_many :guides`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all the guiders who are associated with all the trips.
Have a try with this code

```
def guidersout
@guiders_out = Guider.joins(:trip).all
end
```

I found you have to modify in your model as well.

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :guides, class_name: 'Guider', foreign_key: 'trip_id'
end
```

After modifying your model, you can try with the following code in your controller.

```
def guidersout
    @guiders_out = Trip.all.map{|t| t.guides}.flatten
end
```

In your view, Please change the table.

```
<table width = 60% border =1> 
 <tr>
  <th>Guide # </th>
  <th> Name </th> 
  <th> Phone </th> 
 </tr> 
<% @guiders_out.each do |m| %> 
 <tr>
  <td> <%= m.id %> </td>
  <td> <%= m.name %> </td> 
  <td> <%= m.phone %></td> 
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked but its a weird format, any suggestions ? (im assuming play with the html erb file)

http://imgur.com/fmtEV2i

Comment: I have modified my answer

Comment: i did all of your above suggestions but it still seems to look like the image i linked, any other ? Thanks for all the help !

Comment: I guess, your view page(the html) needs bit change. Can you share your view page for this action.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a method on a collection of ActiveRecord models (i.e. a `Relation`).

To return a collection of each `Guider` of every `Trip`, you'll first need to model your associations properly. Try this

```
class Guider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
end

class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  # NOTE: you must match your association name with its associated class
  has_many :guiders
end
```

Now you can aggregate the collection in the controller like so

```
class ShowguidersController < ApplicationController
  def guidersout
    @guiders_out = Trip.all.collect(&:guiders).flatten
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried and got the error code

NoMethodError in ShowguidersController#guidersout
undefined method `guiders' for #<Trip:0x3db1a88>

Comment: You may need to check your associations. In `Trip` you are referencing `guides` but the class is named `Guider`. By Rails convention, those will need to match up, otherwise you'll have to add some additional options to your association macros.

Answer (score 1):

One `Trip` has many `guiders`, but not the collection.

If you want to get all of it, use:

```
@guiders_out = r.map(&:guiders)
```

Comment: I put that in and got the error
undefined method `arel_table' for Guide:Module